# Custom spring security login page when using mustache

Tags: jsp, spring-security, mustache

I'm trying to create the custom spring security page but when I submit I get the following error: "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?"

I know if we were using plan JSPs we could just add

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

or alternatively the tags/form tag to the JSP. I'm new to moustache and since we don't have access to the EL I can't see a workaround for this. I obviously do not want to disable CSRF protection

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the exact same thing but with mustache syntax if the template engine is set up properly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{_csrf.parameterName}}" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
```

Your example is not JSP but [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) by the way.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Sorry about the example. I just copied that across from a template. Another solution that works is to get the CsrfToken in the controller and pass it to the template